# Autogenerated id using JPA for GAE (key as encoded String)

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus, datastore

**How to declare id field as "Key as encoded String" in JPA entity (not JDO) for usage in GAE Datastore?** You can find example for [JDO](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata?#Keys), but not for JPA.

Can't declare id fields as Long as entity is used in child-parent relations.

So, my entity is like this:

```
@Entity
public class EntityClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String id;
```

So, it uses both JPA and JDO annotations.

So, while trying to persist entity object i'm getting an exception:

Cannot have a null primary key field if the field is unencoded and of type String.  Please provide a value or, if you want the datastore to generate an id on your behalf, change the type of the field to Long.
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.FatalNucleusUserException: Invalid primary key for name.xxx.tips.db.User.  Cannot have a null primary key field if the field is unencoded and of type String.  Please provide a value or, if you want the datastore to generate an id on your behalf, change the type of the field to Long.

Full Stacktrace:
Cannot have a null primary key field if the field is unencoded and of type String.  Please provide a value or, if you want the datastore to generate an id on your behalf, change the type of the field to Long.
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.FatalNucleusUserException: Invalid primary key for name.xxx.tips.db.User.  Cannot have a null primary key field if the field is unencoded and of type String.  Please provide a value or, if you want the datastore to generate an id on your behalf, change the type of the field to Long.
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.storeStringPKField(DatastoreFieldManager.java:540)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastoreFieldManager.storeStringField(DatastoreFieldManager.java:460)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.providedStringField(AbstractStateManager.java:1023)
    at name.xxx.tips.db.User.jdoProvideField(User.java)
    at name.xxx.tips.db.User.jdoProvideFields(User.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.provideFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:2715)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertPreProcess(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:357)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjects(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:267)
    at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:256)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:3185)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.flush(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:4513)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.getExternalObjectId(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1334)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.getObjectId(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1234)
    at name.xxx.tips.db.User.jdoGetObjectId(User.java)
    at org.datanucleus.jpa.JPAAdapter.getIdForObject(JPAAdapter.java:266)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.exists(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1953)
    at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.refresh(EntityManagerImpl.java:469)

Comment: Entity is enhanced using [maven plugin](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/enhancer.html#maven) and <api>JPA</api> configuration parameter is specified. according to log enhancement is done successfully. Both JPA and JDO annotations (and enhanced fields) are in .class files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using JDO annotations if using JPA ? 
The annotation to use for extensions with JPA is

```
org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.Extension
```

as shown [here](http://www.datanucleus.org/javadocs/api.jpa/3.1/)

Comment: changed to use String instead of Key (also use org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.Extension). Then getting another error: Cannot have a java.lang.String primary key and be a child object (owning field is name.xxx.tips.db.User.tips).
 at org.datanucleus.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:264)
 at org.datanucleus.jpa.JPAQuery.getSingleResult(JPAQuery.java:224)

Comment: seems that can't use "Key as encoded String" on GAE using JPA

Comment: you can use all that you can with JDO, using JPA. This is because, once the metadata is read in its all treated by the exact same code

Comment: great to know it. Then how to get rid of that exception?

Comment: Also you're using an old version of the GAE JPA plugin. The current one is version 2.1.1. Suggest you upgrade to that while at it

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.Extension;

@Entity
public class ChildEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String Id;
```

This works for me.